# How display on an HTML a list of objects (ManyToMany) that is a class attribute

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I am a Django beginner, so I hope my question makes sense.

I am trying to understand the very basics of how a cart application works. No sessions involved. Also, I would like to display everything on the homepage, so that the order 'summary' will be always visible and updated on one page.

As I said, I am just learning Django, so I have created two models, Item and Cart

'models.py'

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order number: %s' % self.id
```

a view for the homepage in 'views.py'

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Cart, Item


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()
    carts = Cart.objects.all()
    length = len(Cart.objects.all())
    cart = carts[length - 1]
    cart_items = cart.items
    return render(request, 'cart/home.html', {'cart': cart,
                                              'items': items,
                                              'cart_items': cart_items})
```

mapped in 'urls.py' (included in the main 'urls.py')

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home')
]
```

I have registered both the models in the admin, even though I know the cart should not be, but for the sake of testing, I have created a few items and a few orders.

Now on my template, I have managed to show the items available in the menu, the current, and therefore last order id, but I cannot access the items inside the cart.

As you can see from my basic template, the `cart_items` variable that I have defined in the view and that I pass in the context, return `cart.Item.None`, although it actually contains 3 items.

[image]

this is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><h1>Menu</h1></div>
{% for item in items %}
<ul>{{ item }}</ul>
{% endfor %}
<div><h1>Order</h1></div>
{{ cart }}
{{ cart_items }}
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if that has to be accessed from the HTML through the Django template language, or in the view by passing the variable in the context

To sum up, I would like to see right next to Order id: 'the number', something like 'Pizza 9.99, Coca Cola 3.5'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div><h1>Order</h1></div>
<div>{{ cart }}</div>
{% for item in cart_items %}
    <ul>{{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

#### Update:

you need to remake your view too

```
cart_items = cart.items.all()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your solution but it returns a 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable error